# Is CSS Scaling More Efficient than drawImage Scaling?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, scaling, css-transforms, drawimage

I would like to know what the difference between scaling with `drawImage` and CSS is. I have tried both and CSS seems to give slightly smoother results, while `drawImage` tends to be a little distorted - especially if I am panning the image, blitting from different source x and y over the course of several animation frames. I have drawn this conclusion after testing at many different scale factors. I have a simple example below.

```
var img = new Image();
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

img.src = "img1000x1000.png";// width and height are 1000

ctx.canvas.width  = 100;
ctx.canvas.height = 100;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

This runs after img fully loads.

```
// method 1 uses drawImage to scale
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 200, 200);

// method 2 draws the img with no scaling and then uses css to scale
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.canvas.style.width  = 200;
ctx.canvas.style.height = 200;
```

Keep in mind, I am not always scaling exactly 2x the size and I am blitting from different areas of the img. I only hand in whole numbers to drawImage to keep things as crisp as possible. I also have `image-rendering:pixelated` and the other variants of that defined on the canvas in CSS for the CSS scaling to keep things crisp.

I know for my specific example I could just scale the img up once and pan around the final scaled img, but that is not the question. The question is which is more performant. For my application I must scale up an animated tile map on every frame, so I am blitting from multiple sources to a canvas in 1:1 space and then scaling up the final canvas 30 to 60 times per second using requestAnimationFrame.

In the end, they give very similar results. CSS is barely more crisp and true to the original image. Is CSS faster / more efficient? Or is scaling with drawImage more performant?

NOTE / EDIT:

I found that if I'm using standards mode with `<!DOCTYPE html>` I must pass string values into `style.width` and `style.height` for the CSS method. So if you are using standards mode, make sure to set those to `"200px"` instead of just `200` or your canvas will not scale.

Comment: CSS will be faster.

Comment: I tend to agree, but I have no proof. I imagine it's hardware accelerated like everything else CSS does. It's probably also the method I'll stick with. I was unable to find any speed comparison or explanation online, however. The three main options I saw were `ctx.drawImage`, `ctx.scale`, and CSS styles. I haven't tried `scale` yet. So far I'm just going with CSS because it looks cleaner and requires 1 less call to `drawImage` per frame.

Comment: Seems like something that's measurable using tests that you can create and run...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, if I find the answer I'll post it here or someone else might. Either way it'll come in handy for whoever else has this question. That's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Canvas Alpha makes the difference

For the best results you should keep the canvas size the same as its resolution. If the canvas does not have any transparent pixels you should turn off alpha.

Turn off canvas alpha using `const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d",{alpha: false})`

### Scaling is irrelevant

For most devices scaling is no more expensive an operation than drawing an unscaled image.

The cost of rendering comes downs to the number of pixels that are drawn, not the number of pixels in the source.

### Estimating rendering cost

#### Cost of `drawImage`

If the canvas resolution is 200 by 200 and you draw an image `ctx.drawImage` that fills it that is 40,000 pixels that need to be rendered.

#### Cost of compositing

If that canvas is scaled via CSS rule, even if alpha is off, the canvas element must be composited to be displayed. The cost will be the number of pixels that the canvas size occupies.

If the canvas has alpha as true then it must be composited with the background and thus the rendering cost is the display size of the canvas in pixels.

If the canvas size (CSS) matches the resolution and alpha is off then the canvas does not need to be composited for the final presentation, and there is no additional compositing cost.

### Rendering cost examples

- `canvas` is a visible canvas element
- `image` is an image that can fit in GPU RAM

Best with alpha off and no CSS scaling

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = "100px";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100);

// Total rendering cost 100 * 100 = 10,000 pixels
```

Scaling via CSS and alpha off

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = 200;
canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = "100px";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
ctx.drawImage(image, 200, 200);

// Total rendering cost 200 * 200 + 100 * 100 = 50,000 pixels
```

Rendering with alpha on, no CSS scaling

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = 100;
canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = "100px";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  // alpha is on
// same as const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: true});
ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100);

// Total rendering cost 100 * 100 + 100 * 100 = 20,000 pixels
```

#### Notes

- There is an unavoidable rendering cost due to the page set up, scrolling and various other factors. These costs are ignored as they can not be avoided.
- The option to turn of alpha may not be available on all browsers.
- Software rendering and device capabilities will have the most dramatic effect on rendering performance.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that it's not so much which function is used to composite, but more so the size of the image that needs to be composited. That makes sense. Still, I can't help but notice that the actual scaling is done differently by CSS. It's actually noticeably cleaner for upscaling than `drawImage`. This leads me to believe that a different algorithm is used. I do turn off alpha. I am implementing all the tips listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas one of which is to not use drawImage on every frame.

Comment: @Frank Yes Chrome (I know) uses a different shader for the canvas. You can however change the quality settings via `ctx.imageSmoothingQuality` to `"low"` (default) `"medium"`, or `"high"` which will change the sampling method of scaled images when combined with `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true`

Comment: That is an excellent tip. I almost always turn imageSmoothing off, but I will certainly take a look at the CanvasRenderingContext2D specs again to see if there's anything else I can do to increase performance.

Comment: @Frank For best performance you can use WebGL to render 2D content. Its a little more complex, but because WebGL lets you better organize state changes (communication between CPU <> GPU) you can get a huge performance gain. Eg  Average laptop... 2D context peaks at 2000 rotated scaled faded transparent sprites 60Hz (2000 state changes).  WebGL  batching ~256 sprites per call can do 32000 (128 state changes) of the same sprite at 60Hz (64000 if active cooling and external fan to bleed off heat)